# Limit Map of Discrete Dynamical System

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $f:H\rightarrow H$ be a countinuous map from the separable hilbert space into itself, for every $x\in H$ define the discrete dynamical system
$$
\xi_x^{n+1}\triangleq f(\xi^n_x);\qquad \xi^0_x\triangleq x.
$$
Define the map $\Phi_f$ from $H$ to itself by
$$
\Phi(x)\triangleq \lim\limits_{n \mapsto \infty} \xi_x^n.
$$

What properties does $f$ need to satisfy so that $\Phi_f$ has dense orbit in $H$?